# Java - How to filter 2D string array

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array, filter

I have the 2D object array rowData[][]

The array is initialized as follows:

```
List rows = new ArrayList();
while(rs.next()) {
   String[] row = new String[columnCount];
   for(int i = 1; i <= columnCount; i++){
      row[i-1] = rs.getString(i);
   }
   rows.add(row);
}
String[][] rowData = (String[][])rows.toArray(new String[rows.size()][columnCount]);
```

```
System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(rowData));
```

gives me the output:

```
[[AUDI, A1, 16890.0, BLAU, 6292, 2018-03-12, 82,  1.0 TFSI, BENZIN, KLEINWAGEN, 1, 9PGAUBB646B8BA022], [AUDI, A5, 39500.0, GOLD, 25000, 2016-07-04, 224, 2.0 TFSI, BENZIN, LIMOUSINE, 1, GWAUZZZ8P8BA06423]]
```

Is it possible to filter out specific criteria like "Audi" or "16890.0"?
I only found help for filtering out integers.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is this a String array or Object array?

Comment: Sorry, it's an object array

Comment: Do share how you have initialized it

Comment: That is a *String* array not an *Object* array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may do so using:

```
Arrays.stream(rowData).flatMap(Arrays::stream)
                      .filter(s -> s.equals("AUDI") || s.equals("16890.0"))
                      .forEach(System.out::println);
```

which outputs:

> AUDI
>
> 16890.0
>
> AUDI
>
> 16890.0

Answer (score 1):

If you do not have a constraint on what data structure you use, using a list is much easier to handle filtering based on just a value. To illustrate:

```
List<List> result = new ArrayList<>();
while (rs.next()) {
    List row = new ArrayList(columnCount);
    for (int i = 1; i <= columnCount; i++) {
        row.add(rs.getString(i));
    }
    result.add(row);
}

result.stream().filter(list -> list.contains(lookupValue)).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

You can, of course, transform it into an array if need be.